# how to bind data from sqlite to table view in blackberry?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, tableview, data-binding

I am new for Blackberry.  how to bind data from sqlite to table view in blackberry? Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the rows in the database into a vector and then do whatever you want with the vector